# Best way to sync SQL 2000 and 2005 databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a production database in SQL 2000 and a SQL 2005 instance will be installed in a new server. I would like to have an updated copy of one SQL 2000 database in my SQL 2005 at anytime.

What is the best way to implement database sync between this two SQL versions?

Comment: You aren't going to develop on a SQL Server 2005 database for the prod 2000 database are you? You should never develop on a database version that is higher than prod as you will end up using code that won't work in prod. If you are doing this to prep the database for upgrading, then ignore this (although you should go to 2008 if you are doing that as a new version is expected next year and even 2005 is wildly out of date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an SSIS package to do this and schedule it as a job.

Or if this is development machine that you want to keep  you can do all the development on the 2005 database in scripts kept in source control (which is of course what you should be doing), then you take the most recent backup, restore it to the database and run any change scripts you need.

Or use Red_gate's SQL data compare. It costs money but its worth it.

Answer (score 0):

if "anytime" means you need the data to be updated as soon as it changes, i would think about triggering the tables on the 2000 server to mirror the operation on the 2005 server.

or, a DTS on the 2000 server might do the job, but i have no experience with those (they are also deprecated if i'm not mistaken).

or, some scheduled jobs might keep data in sync between the servers (but they'll be out of sync until the next job run)

hope this helps, myself i'd go with triggering since it's a "set and forget" approach.

Comment: DTS can;t go to SQL Server 2005, but a SQL Server 2005 SSIS pacakage can pick up from a 2000 database.